# HTTP GET requests data endlessly

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, angular

I can't figure out why my code requests data endlessly. In my service I get data which is an Array of Objects. I want to do all my http, map, subscribe in the service, because I need that the service to contain the local array, because I need that Array in the rest of my webpage. Using the developer tool in the browser the get method gets requested endlessly, until my browser crashes.

Worth noticing is that the incoming data is not a "file.json", but an plain URL. In the backend I use the Jackson objectmapper for sending my data as an Array with objects.

BTW, when I modify the code to service only sending the http.get('someUrl') and doing map and subscribe in the component, it works fine. I could also use some help with the delete Data-methods, I didn't get it to work when I modified it as well to do the mapping and subscription in the component.

Hope you can see some obvious errors!

The codes that loop endlessly:

MyService:

```
export class MyService {

    private dummys: Array<Dummy>;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.dummys = new Array<Dummy>();
    }
    getData() {
        this.http.get('someUrl')
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(dummys => this.dummys = dummys);
        return this.dummys;
    }

    saveData(dummy: Dummy) {

        let body = JSON.stringify(dummy);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        this.http.get('someUrl', body, options)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(dummy => this.dummys.push(dummy));
        return this.dummys;
    }

    deleteData() {

        let index = this.dummys.indexOf(dummy);

        let body = JSON.stringify(dummy);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        this.http.post('someUrl', body, options)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(dummy => this.dummys = this.dummys.splice(index, 1);
        return this.dummys;
    }
}
```

MyComponent:

```
export class MyComponent {

    name: string;
    id: string;
    date: string;
    dummys: Array<Dummy>;

    constructor(public _myService: MyService, public _router: Router) { }

    getDatas() {
        this._myService.getData()
    }

    saveDatas() {
        let dummy = new Dummy(this.id, this.name, this.date)
        this._myService.saveData(dummy)
        this.name = '';
        this._myService.getData();
    }

    deleteDatas(dummy) {
        this._myService.deleteData(dummy);
        this._myService.getData();
    }

}
```

My template in MyComponent:

```
<form (submit)="saveDatas()">
    <input required [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="Add data">
</form>
<br>
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of getDatas()">
    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    <td> {{data.date}} </td>
    <td><button (click)="removeDatas(data)">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the response code the HTTP request returns? It might be return a redirect response(302)

Comment: No code at all actually, when I look at the network activity it shows no status whatsoever... just the getmethod a million times.... and then it crashes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe the the Observable in MyComponent and return a Observable in your service:

```
export class MyService {

...

getData() {
    return this.http.get('someUrl')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
}

...
}

export class MyComponent {

...

ngOnInit() {
   this.getDatas();
}

getDatas() {
    this._myService.getData().subscribe(
        response => { this.datas = response});
}
...
}
```

And in your template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of datas">
```

Comment: Yes, well this works. But does this not mean that the dummy-data are "stored" in the local "dummies"-Array in the component. Because I need it to be in the local dummys array in the service. Because I have a feature that when the user clicks the "Dummy" in the component, the user gets navigated to another page, and that method is in the service. So now I get the error "cannot read property .... of null", which points to that the local array in the service is null I assume. Sorry if I am stupid, but I'm totally new to http ;)

Comment: you have access to myService attributes in MyComponent. Add the values there.

Comment: Okay, I'm not really sure what you mean. I mean, I was trying to add the values in the service-array, and return the current content of the array back and forth to the component. Which brings to my original question: the get-request just gets repeated until browser crashes...